# Link content provider to database

Tags: android, sql, database, android-contentprovider, mlab

I am developing an android app with Google Maps.
Basically what a I want to do is to store the location where the user clicks in a database, but I want to store this information for all users that have the app.

I already read about SQLite in Android and his stuff but seems like I only can create a local file where I can store information. I want this information to be sync everytime the app is opened. I don't know how neither where store this information online.

Do I need something like [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) or any other database server to achieve this?

Thanks for all.

**UPDATE 09/10:54**

I recently discover that [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/) gives you a simple database to use. In every sample I see for Content Providers in Android or Sync Adapters, I never saw a single database call nor declaration anywhere.

How you can link a content provider or sync adapter to a database?

**UPDATE 09/11:24**

In the [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/intro_to_content_providers/part_3_-_creating_a_custom_contentprovider/) you can learn how to create a custom Content Provider, but again ... no database is included or mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sync Adapters](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html):

> Synchronizing data between an Android device and web servers can make your application significantly more useful and compelling for your users. For example, transferring data to a web server makes a useful backup, and transferring data from a server makes it available to the user even when the device is offline. In some cases, users may find it easier to enter and edit their data in a web interface and then have that data available on their device, or they may want to collect data over time and then upload it to a central storage area.